# Anchor Element : "Element is not selectable" error in PhantomJS

Tags: jquery, selenium, phantomjs

I am trying to automate an Anchor tag click using PhantomJs in C#.Net.
I am able to find the element and it is showing the **Visible** and **Displayed** property as True. That is fine.

But it is not selecting the web element. I have tried to set the element to be selected, but it is showing "**Element is not selectable**" and I am not able to perform Click event on that. The same piece of code is working fine FireFox.

**Tried with :** ExpectedConditions.ElementToBeSelected(we));

**Exception Details:**

{"{\"errorMessage\":\"Element is not selectable\",\"request\":{\"headers\"}}

**HTML Element : Anchor tag**

a id="ReportViewer1_ReportToolbar_ExportGr_Export" title="Export" class="DisabledLink" href="#">Export

Can any one please tell me what could be the reason for "Element Not Selectable"

Thanks

Comment: have you tried ExpectedConditions.ElementToBeSelectable(we)

Comment: yes, tried. I have tried with the Overloaded method as well.

Comment: Try using actions class with moveToElement() function

Comment: Thanks Kushal for reply, I have tried this as well.But no luck.It is working fine in FireFox, but in PhantomJs it is saying that the Element is not selectable..  IWebElement element = driver.FindElement(By.Id("Print_Button"));
Actions action = new Actions(driver);
action.MoveToElement(element).Click().Perform();

Comment: Use bud().perform();